# Is it possible to add a popup on application launch depending on the following?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, if-statement

I am creating a C# WPF application and I'm not the best with it to be honest.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do the following.

When the application launches I want it to automatically check a table in a local database and the table is empty, create a pop up that prompts the user to insert the values it needs to fill those rows?

Is this possible or am I going to have to think of an alternative design?

At the moment I have in my Window_loaded:

```
if (limit.UL == null && limit.LL == null)
{
    limitWindow = new LimitWindow();
}
```

where limit.UL and limit.LL are columns in my table, but not having any luck due to them not being objects.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure it's possible. Fire a select statement on the database and let the window pop up or don't. ;o) To the rest of your post, you have to provide more detail. How is the data loaded a.s.o....

Comment: @DHN Last comment probably made no sense. It connects by using an ADO.NET entity framework as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to you to override the `Application.OnStartup` method in your App.xaml.cs file. In there, I would perform the check whether your data exists. If it does not, I would create your `LimitWindow` and show it as a dialog.
After that the applications main window can be initialized and shown. The code would look somewhat like this:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    // Check if the database needs to be updated; if yes, show the corresponding window as a dialog
    var limit = CheckLimit();
    if (limit.UL == null && limit.LL == null)
    {
        var limitWindow = new LimitWindow();
        var dialogResult = limitWindow.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult)
        {
            // Update your database here
        }
    }

    // Show the actual main window of the application after the check
    this.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
    this.MainWindow.Show();
}
```

Keep in mind that you should remove the `StartupUri` attribute from the `Application` element in the App.xaml file.

The `CheckLimit` function would instantiate the `DbContext` or the `ObjectContext` of entity framework and perform the query, normally using LINQ:

```
private Limit CheckLimit()
{
    // Create the context and perform the query
    var dbContext = new ClassDerivedFromDbContext();
    var limit = dbContext.Limits.FirstOrDefault();
    dbContext.Close();
    return limit;
}
```

As I don't know how your entity framework classes look like, you would have to implement `CheckLimit` by yourself.

Hope this helps.